# Is Kotlin IR the final product that runs in a virtual machine as it is?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

It is known that programming languages ​​in which virtual machines exist exist before the virtual machine reads them into machine language, but there is an intermediate language 'closer to machine language than the language written by actual developers'.

For example, in the case of C#, when you build a program in C#, that C# is built as C# IL code, which is neither pure C nor C#.

In the case of Java, when building an app with Java, the result in Java byte code is output.

Returning to the main topic, in the case of Kotlin, it was previously understood that it was converted to Java and finally passed Java byte code to the virtual machine. (Maybe this is where I misunderstood)

However, in the case of [Kotlin IR](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/02/the-jvm-backend-is-in-beta-let-s-make-it-stable-together/), which is mentioned when using Jetpack Compose, it is described as if it is the final binary that is read directly from the virtual machine (similar to C#'s IL from the name).

So what I want to ask is this.

Is Kotlin IR a binary that can be read and operated by the JVM directly without being converted back to java at the compilation stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin code is never converted to Java during compilation. It's compiled to Java bytecode. Kotlin IR is an intermediate representation between your written Kotlin code and the compiled Java bytecode, an intermediate step used during compilation. It is not part of your compiled code.

The JVM doesn't know anything about Kotlin or Kotlin IR.

Kotlin IR is used in the other platform targets of Kotlin besides JVM, also as an intermediate step.